# How can I load a different log directory in Tensorboard after the first session on Windows 11?

Tags: pytorch, tensorboard, windows-11

I can't load my log directory by specifying the 'logdir' of tensorboard after a first tensorboard session. Once tensorboard successfully loads the first log directory, at each session afterwards it just keeps loading the same first directory and seems to ignore the 'logdir' parameter(even if I start tensorboard like this: `tensorboard --logdir [nonsense]`). The only way to load another log directory is to restart my computer.

A way to reproduce my problem is like this:

1. First use torch.utils.tensorboard.SummaryWriter to log some information in ./runs/logdir1
2. Do the same but log into ./runs/logdir2
3. Use tensorflow to view ./runs/logdir1: `tensorboard --logdir ./runs/logdir1.`
4. Now you can open the url and see the information, so far so good.
5. Ctrl + C to stop the session and start another session: `tensorboard --logdir ./runs/logdir2.`
6. No error information, but if you open the url, you will find it's still in ./runs/logdir1
7. Ctrl + C to stop. Then try `tensorboard --logdir <some random word>`
8. Still no error information and still in ./runs/logdir1.

I searched on Google but can't find a similar problem. I don't know if that's because I'm not using tensorboard right. My OS is Win11 by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have opened a TensorBoard session (default port 6006) with some directory.

The next time, even if you set another whole directory, it will reload the previous one. Why? You might ask. You are using the same port as the previous session.

I personally don't like such design, but, **just change the port**.

On restart it works as expected *probably* because it relies on some temp files, that are cleaned upon reboot. Just gussing here, I will look at TB code to be sure.